# I can use it when I type python commands in EC2, but when I do python commands in Laravel's process exec, I can't use it

Tags: python, laravel, shell, amazon-ec2, command

## What I want to do

I want to use python3 commands in the code I created within the Laravel project in EC2.

## Environment

AWS EC2 AmazonLinux

Laravel6

## Problem

In the Laravel project.

```
$path = '../file.py';
$process = new Process(['python3', $path]);
$process->mustRun();
```

#### messsage

```
The command "'python3' '../directory/file.py' '6'" failed.
Exit Code: 127(Command not found)
Working directory: /var/www/html/my-laravel-project/public
Output:
================
Error Output:
================
sh: line 0: exec: python3: not found
```

## What I did

### python3 is installed

in EC2

```
python3 --version
```

```
Python 3.9.0
```

### of course It works fine locally.

Dear all, what should I try?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `which python` and give full path? e.g `/usr/bin/python` instead of just `python`?